# Cloned Django app on Ubuntu with Nginx and uwsgi

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi

So recently I just cloned my instance in order to add it to a load balancer. Everything is set up fine but I can't help thinking that I am missing something. It has been a while and my friend set up my first server. Is there somewhere that I must add the new Public Ip of my Clone server? Perhaps the `Allowed Host` in fabfile.py?

Heres exactly what I have done:

1. Clone the server
2. Git pull
3. Add to loadbalancer

Am I missing a step somewhere that I add the new IP? Sometimes I get a `Django Invalid External IP` message. Im guessing it's when clone server tries to make requests.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to add the balancer's ip to ALLOWED_HOSTS config

See [Django's config](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts)

And also make sure your domain's DNS settings all point where they should (the load balancer i would think) or try with cURL and it's awesome --resolve

Comment: So my ALLOWED_HOSTS config has my domain name. Don't I have to link my domain name to my new IP?

Comment: I'm sorry it's hard for me to evaluate things i don't know or to help you correctly based on the informations i know.

Comment: i will try... but first...

Is this a real situation or are you trying to get help prentending you have some experience? If so, you should check out if the place you cloned the repository from have some sort of help/forum.

If not, and i'm just not fully understanding the question (could also be language barrier). Check the link i posted and read what it says. I have no idea about your setup, you should be able to see if the setting needs modifying from the documentation.

If your domain points to a load balancer, then i think the load balancer ip should also be allowed in there.Thanks

Comment: It is a mix. This is a real situtation. I have experience but I am also limited as my partner had decided to leave me with a load balancer with a broken instance. Therefore, I cloned the working instance and now i am here.This is a real situation and I have experience, just not with a load balancer. I'm assuming I am doing everything correctly but every once in a while i get a Django ERROR External IP and it makes me feel like i'm missing something. Also, when i stop the original instance and i just run the cloned instance i get a Gateway error 500.